# Ubuntu Phone (Aquaris 4.5) How to connect to a wifi network wich requires an account?

Tags: networking, wireless, authentication, phone

So I tried to login to the WiFi network at my University, which requires an account and password, but I never came that far. Whenever I select one of the networks (there are 2 usable networks) it loads the WiFi-menu. Other networks are working great but none of which require an account and password to login.

[Informations about the networks here (German)](http://www.urz.ovgu.de/Unsere+Leistungen/Datennetz/Campus/WLAN.html)

Comment: **didyouseekyle:** the best you can do is subscribe to this bug and mention "affects me too".  **@aimar:** Please convert your comment into an answer as "there's a bug" *is* an answer in itself.  (and leave a comment to me so I can come and upvote!)

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `wich` to `which` so that English translating programs can work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is a bug opened [here‌​](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-network/+bug/1417646). Others seem to make it work [here](http://www.danbishop.org/2015/02/21/add-eduroam-or-any-other-802-1x-wireless-network-to-ubuntu-phone/), mine does not connect this way.

Comment: I GOT IT! Thanks to the new comment provided by @Markcortbass [here](http://www.danbishop.org/2015/02/21/add-eduroam-or-any-other-802-1x-wireless-network-to-ubuntu-phone/). I also set the path properly for the ca.pem file adding to the string: \nca-cert=etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ca.pem

Comment: please [edit] this answer to extract the insights from the external source and write them into this answer.  When answers fully rely on hyperlinks to resolve questions, they are considered Not An Answer on most Stack Exchange sites because if the link moves/dies, then so does the knowledge in the answer.